# Python - Data Scraping Tables

Tags: python

I'm attempting to scrape data for all the quarterbacks who have been drafted. http://www.nfl.com/draft/history/fulldraft?type=position

I'm able to scrape the data. However, there are blank lines that I cannot get rid of. [Excel file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBYlA.jpg)

Here is the code that I used.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

def make_soup(url):
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
return soupdata

playerdata = playerdatasaved = ""
soup = make_soup("http://www.nfl.com/draft/history/fulldraft?type=position")

for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
playerdata = ""
   for data in record.findAll('td'):
       playerdata = playerdata + "," + data.text
   if len(playerdata)!= 0:
       playerdatasaved = playerdatasaved + "\n" + playerdata[1:]

header = "Round, Selection #, Player, Position, School, Team   Drafted" + "\n"

file = open("Quarterbacks.csv","wb")
file.write(bytes(header, encoding = "ascii", errors = 'igonore'))
file.write(bytes(playerdatasaved, encoding = "ascii", errors = 'igonore'))
```

I've tried to use an if statement to check for \n breaks and remove the breaks. Also, I've tried to turn the data into a string and use a replace or split command. None of these corrected the issue.

Thanks for any help that you can give me!

Comment: playerdata = playerdata + "," + data.text.rstrip('\n')  ?

Comment: I tried that, and it removed one of the line breaks. Using your logic, I tried "data.text.replace('\n', '')" and it worked. Thanks for the help!!